# Springboot JPA/hibernate: how to map one table multiple entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm creating a system where I have some entities that have some properties that are common, like address (with street, number, zip etc.) and phone (number, type, etc.) and I don't want to repeat these columns on each entity.

Here' a example:

- Student has address and phone
- Teacher has multiple addresses (home
  and office) and multiple phones (home, mobile, office)
- StaffMember
  has address and multiple phones (home, mobile and office)

I've used something like that while developing Ruby On Rails using polymorphic associations. I've searched for something like on Java/JPA/Hibernate and couldn't find something much like it. I've found many things about JPA inheritance but I don't quite understand it.

Can you give me a example on how to model it and how to use it?

**EDIT**

After reading my question I think it's not clear enough, so let me add here the database schema I have:

```
Student
-------
id bigint
name varchar
birth_date date
...

Teacher
-------
id bigint
name varchar
birth_date date
department varchar
...

StaffMember
-------
id bigint
name varchar
birth_date date
department varchar
function varchar
...

Address
-------
id bigint
street varchar
number int
...
entity_id bigint
entity_type varchar

Phone
-----
id bigint
type varchar
number varchar
...
entity_id bigint
entity_type varchar
```

And for both `Address` and `Phone` the columns `entity_id` and `entity_type` are references to `Student`, `Teacher` and `StaffMember`.

But how to map it using Hibernate/JPA?

Comment: Just to be sure: Your database schema is fixed an JPA/hibernate has to adapt it?

Comment: Hi @larsgrefer, no the schema is flexible enough, above is just an example of what it thought it would be the best, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: When you are using spring-boot, just set `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and let hibernate generate the schema for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using Hibernate-specific annotations, there are the [@Any](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-any) and [@AnyDef](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-any) annotations that do what you want. You will need to specify a [@MetaValue](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-any) entry for each entity type related to Address so Hibernate knows how to store the proper value for item_type

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Any;
import org.hibernate.annotations.AnyMetaDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.MetaValue;

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "ITEM_TYPE"))
    @AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string",
            metaValues = {
                    @MetaValue(targetEntity = Student.class, value = "STUDENT"),
                    @MetaValue(targetEntity = Teacher.class, value = "TEACHER")
            })
    @JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID")
    private Object item;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String type;

    @Column
    private String street;

    @Column
    private int number;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


    public Object getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Object item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" +
                "person=" + item +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", street='" + street + '\'' +
                ", number=" + number +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Now, you can just use Address in any bean that has the proper @MetaValue entry, both as @ManyToOne association:

```
@ManyToOne
protected Address address;
```

Or a @OneToMany  association:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
protected Collection<Address> addresses;
```

I created a simple test project using Spring Boot and it seemed to work nicely!

Comment: Thanks @João Marcus, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Please explain "..that has the proper @MetaValue entry". This way I am getting unidirectional `@OneToMany` relation from `Student` to `Addresses` which creates an additional `students_addresses`, `teachers_addresses` table due to lack of `mappedBy` attribute which cannot be defined. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use a generic repository class.

This post http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/12/18/handling-entities-inheritance-with-spring-data-jpa explains pretty much it. Let me know if works for you.

Comment: Hi @Nicolas Fontenele, that's not exactly what I want (or I interpreted it wrong). I've added a little bit more of detail to my question, so it might help you understand better. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
   @Embeddable
   public class Address {
        // Fields & accessors
        // Do the Phone class in similar fashion
   }

   @Entity
   @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "entity_type")
   public abstract class Person {
        @Id
        private Integer id;

        private String name;

        @Embedded 
        private Address homeAddress;

        @Embedded 
        private Phone homePhone;

       // Other shared fields & accessors

   }

   @Entity
   public abstract class Employee extends Person {

        @Embedded 
        private Phone mobilePhone;

        @Embedded 
        private Phone officePhone;

       //...

    }

    @Entity
    public class Students extends Person {

    }

    @Entity
    public class StaffMember extends Employeee {

    }

    @Entity
    public class Teacher extends Employeee {

      @Embedded
      private Address officeAddress;

      // Accessors & other ...
   }
```

Comment: Hi @dev-null by using Embeddable can I have Address being stored in a separate table? I don't want to replicate this structure on each table on my database.

Comment: The point of @Embeddable is that it does not have special table it is just the data structure embedded in the other tables. Something like compound data type.